# Disable video player for background video ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, video

I want to have a background video for the landing page of a web app. I'm using ReactJs.

Everything works but with some navigators, video controls appears. How to remove that ?

Here is my code :

html :

```
<video className="Video" autoPlay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
     <source src={videoSource} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

css :

```
.Video {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `controls={false}` to force controls to be hidden:

```js
const Demo = ({ videoSource }) => (
  <video
    controls={false}
    autoPlay
    muted
    loop
    className="Video"
  >
    <source src={videoSource} type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo 
    videoSource="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/360/Big_Buck_Bunny_360_10s_1MB.mp4" />,
  root
);
```

```css
.Video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/** hide the snippet's console **/
.as-console-row {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: That does work in some explorer but not all, for example, android and iOs